# How can I edit Service Appointments via Field Service Lightning Mobile App?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, permission-sets, field-service-lightning, fieldservice

Recently I've implemented Field Service Lightning into my workforce. Sadly I've come up with an unexpected blocker. My technicians can't edit the Service Appointments via mobile app that have been assigned to them. I've already checked the profile permission, but nothing has happened so far. Any suggestions on how to enable editing of this object via the mobile app?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Setup
Enter and go to "Field Service Mobile settings"
Find the "Enable Full Edit on Records" checkbox and check it and click save.

----In the Mobile App-----
Go to "Settings"
Tap "Clear Purged Data"
You should now be able to edit records.

Answer (score -1):

Technicians cannot edit Service Appointment status directly from FSL mobile app , you need to set up a Flow of type Field Service Mobile Flow and expose it to Technicians through App Extension from Field Service Mobile Settings.

Please refer this help article:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mfs_limits.htm&type=5

Comment: You absolutely can edit a Service Appointment directly in the mobile application.